# Kernel density plot bandwidth in ggplot2 with `facet_wrap`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use `stat_density()` and `facet_wrap()` in the `ggplot2` package to create kernel density plots for different groupings, but I want to make sure that I use the same bandwidth for every plot. Can I be sure that `stat_density()` uses the same bandwidth for every plot?

For example, using `diamonds`:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) + 
  stat_density() + 
  facet_wrap(~ cut) + 
  scale_x_log()
```

In the documentation it shows that I can use `adjust` to adjust the automatic bandwidth, but this just applies a multiple and returns me to the original question. `stat_density()` also has a `...` option, but I haven't been able to pass though the `density()` option `bw`, like this:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat)) + 
  stat_density(bw = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~ cut) + 
  scale_x_log()
```

So, if `stat_density()` isn't using the same bandwidth across all facets, is there a way that I can force this? I tried a `ddply()` solution with `transform()` and `density()`, but this fails because `density()` doesn't necessarily return the same number of x and y values as the input. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit**
It looks like `ggplot2` assigns an optimal bandwidth to each facet (it looks like @Ramnath and Dianardo, Fortin, and Lemieux *Econometrica* 1996 agree with this), not the constant bandwidth I was seeking. But, if I did want a constant bandwidth across all facets, my attempt below fails.

```
my.density <- function(x) {
    temp <- density(x$carat, bw = 0.5)
    return(data.frame(carat = temp$x, density = temp$y))
}
temp <- ddply(diamonds, .(cut), my.density)
ggplot(temp, aes(x = carat, y = density)) + 
             geom_point() + 
             facet_wrap(~ cut) + 
             scale_x_log()
Warning messages:
1: In match.fun(get(".transform", .))(values) : NaNs produced
2: In match.fun(get(".transform", .))(values) : NaNs produced
3: In match.fun(get(".transform", .))(values) : NaNs produced
4: In match.fun(get(".transform", .))(values) : NaNs produced
5: In match.fun(get(".transform", .))(values) : NaNs produced
6: Removed 84 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
7: Removed 113 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
8: Removed 98 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
9: Removed 98 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
10: Removed 106 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `stat_density` it seems to be using the default version of `density`. digging further, looking at the documentation for `density`, you find that it uses `bw.nrd0` method to compute bandwidth. you should look at this description and figure out how to pre-transform your data so that you are able to achieve your objective.

Comment: @Ramnath -- Thanks! I had followed that path, but couldn't myself any closer to an answer. But maybe that makes my fundamental question, "Which `stat_density()` parameters are set using info from all facets? And which are set within each facet?"

Comment: @richardh -- I think that statistical transformations are applied after faceting the data. Hence, if the `bw.nrd0` method computes bandwidth based on the data, then you would have different bandwidths in the facets. To get more control, my suggestion would be to use `ddply` and compute the density estimates as you want them and then pass it to `ggplot` as an `aesthetic`. I can cook up an example if you would like. Out of curiousity, why would you want the same bandwidth across all plots?

Comment: @Ramnath -- Good point on the bandwidth! I checked the "reference" for this technique (Dinardo, Fortin, and Lemieux _Econometrica_ 1996) and it looks like they do use variable bandwidth, set optimally for each facet. I'll make sure we really want constant bandwidth. But for my own education, I would love to see how you would do it -- my approach fails (I'll paste above).

Comment: @richard -- your code works for me and it produces  a plot. it returns warnings but that is because you invoke `scale_log_x` and some of the numbers are really small. if you remove `scale_log_x` you see the density plots without any warnings.

Comment: @richard -- actually the warnings are on account of the negative values for `carat` in `my.density`. a slight modification of your code would do the trick: `ggplot(temp, aes(x = carat, y = density)) + geom_line(subset = .(carat > 0)) + facet_wrap(~ cut) + scale_x_log()`. let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: @Ramnath -- D'oh! And that explains the lop-sided plot (although in the meantime I convinced someone that optimal bandwidth in each facet is the way to go). I think this is all wrapped up. Thanks for all of your help! If you're busy, then I can write this up and mark answered. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings are on account of the negative values for `carat` in `my.density`. A slight modification of your code would do the trick:

```
  ggplot(temp, aes(x = carat, y = density)) + 
    geom_line(subset = .(carat > 0)) +
   facet_wrap(~ cut) + scale_x_log()
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: Technically, it would be even better to use a density estimator that allows you to fix the range of the estimated density.