# R plot density ggplot vs plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, probability-density

I am using the density function in R and then computing some results from the obtained densities. After that, I use the ggplot2 to display the PDFs of the same data.

However, the results are slightly different from what is shown in the respective plot - something that is confirmed by plotting the density output directly (using plot {graphics}).

Any idea why? How can I correct it, so the results and plot (from ggplot2) do match / are from exact same data?

An example of this (code and images):

```
srcdata = data.frame("Value" = c(4.6228, 1.7942, 4.2738, 2.1502, 2.2665, 5.1717, 4.1015, 2.5126, 4.4270, 4.4729, 2.5112, 2.3493, 2.2787, 2.0114, 4.6931, 4.6582, 3.3162, 2.2995, 4.3954, 1.8488), "Type" = c("Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Negative"))

bwidth <- ( density ( srcdata$Value ))$bw

sample <- split ( srcdata$Value, srcdata$Type )[ 1:2 ]

xmin = min(srcdata$Value) - 0.2 * abs(min(srcdata$Value))
xmax = max(srcdata$Value) + 0.2 * abs(max(srcdata$Value))

densities <- lapply ( sample, density, bw = bwidth, n = 512, from = xmin, to = xmax )

#plotting densities result
plot( densities [[ 1 ]], xlim = c(xmin,xmax), col = "steelblue", main = "" )
lines ( densities [[ 2 ]], col = "orange" )

#plot using ggplot2
ggplot(data = srcdata, aes(x=Value)) + geom_density(aes(group=Type, colour=Type)) + xlim(xmin, xmax)

#or with ggplot2 (using easyGgplot2)
ggplot2.density(data=srcdata, xName='Value', groupName='Type', alpha=0.5, xlim=c(xmin,xmax))
```

image:

[image]

Comment: they appear to be using different bandwidths for the radial basis function kernel. If you want them to be the same, you need to specify the same bandwidth

Comment: Yes, you're changing the defaults when calculating the densities yourself, but not when using geom_density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current comments correctly identify that you are using two different bandwidths to calculate densities in your two plots: the `plot()` graph is using the `bwidth` you specified as the bandwidth and the `ggplot()` graph uses the default bandwidth. Ideally you would pass `bwidth` to the ggplot graph and that would solve everything, however the commentary around an SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805122/kernel-density-plot-bandwidth-in-ggplot2-with-facet-wrap) suggests that you can't pass a bandwidth parameter to `stat_density` or `geom_density`.

The easiest thing to do to get the same output in both graphs is to let `density()` determine the optimal bandwidth in both your manual density calculation (below) and in the ggplot graph (using the same code you already have)

```
densities <- lapply ( sample, density, n = 512, from = xmin, to = xmax )
```

Alternatively, the actual binwidth used in geom/stat_density is the pre-determined binwidth times the adjust parameter ([density documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/density.html)) so you could specify an `adjust` value in `stat_density` ([stat_density documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density.html)) in an attempt to try to adjust the ggplot binwidth to match your `bwidth` variable. I found that an adjust value of 4.5 gives a similar (but not exact) version the original graph produced with your calculated densities:

```
ggplot(data = srcdata, aes(x=Value)) + 
    geom_density(aes(group=Type, colour=Type), adjust = 4.5) +
    xlim(xmin, xmax)
```

[image: Adjusted ggplot density graph]

**EDIT** 
You may find the answer to this question helpful if you want to specifically adjust your ggplot graph so that it uses your `bwidth` variable as the binwidth in the density smoothing: [Understanding bandwidth smoothing in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985361/understanding-bandwidth-smoothing-in-ggplot2)

Comment: You're right, thanks!
I was using the bw obtained from all the samples (which is 0.5902679) and forcing that in the plot. However, I'm plotting two curves (groups from the sample data). If no bw is specified, the plot uses the lower bandwidth from the two groups (0.1232133). Thus, it seems adjust = 0.5902679/0.1232133 = 4.79062, or:
adj = bwidth / min((density ( sample[[1]] ))$bw, (density ( sample[[2]] ))$bw)